# Null exception while send mail in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, email

[image][image]My function to send email

```java
    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;[![enter image description here][2]][2]
    public void sendMailConfirm(String receiverAddress, int orderId) {
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setMailFrom(senderAddress);
        mail.setMailTo(receiverAddress);
        mail.setMailSubject(mailSubject);
        mail.setMailContent(mailContent + "\n\nOrder ID: " + orderId);

        mailService.sendMail(mail);
    }
```

My Mail class

```java
public class Mail {
    private String mailFrom;

    private String mailTo;

    private String mailSubject;

    private String mailContent;

    private String contentType;

    private List<Object> attachments;

    getter & setter
```

I wrote this in an API. But when I test this. It returns a null exception. Please help me!

```java
                //  send mail to notif success order
                Manager manager = new Manager();
                manager.sendMailConfirm(orderVM.getEmail(), order.getId());
```

Comment: Error stack please . Also the use of  `new` suggests you are not using spring the correct way

Comment: I'm just uploading an image. How to fix that issue?

Comment: The information shared is not adequate to help you. Here the `order` or `mailService` could be null, but that is a guess. Could you please share all the code that will reproduce this issue . Please try to improve the question with enough information to help you out

Comment: @R.G I don't understand. the ```orderVM.getEmail()``` and ```order.getId()``` always return result not null. Why the function can get null?

Comment: the ```attachments``` is null when I'm sending the order.

Comment: `mailService ` is null and you are not setting attachments to mail in the code shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NullPointerException apparently occur here:

```java
 mailService.sendMail(mail);
```

Make sure that the `mailService` in your `Manager` class is not null.

If you are in a Spring Boot context the `Manager` probably should not be initialized manually but that's just an assumption, as I don't know the rest of the code.

Comment: But I autowired it.

Comment: I mean, you create `Manager manager = new Manager();` by yourself. Or did I miss something?

Comment: As soon as you create the the Manager by yourself, nothing within it gets autowired. But you could autowire the Manager itself. Then the MailService will be probably injected.

Comment: How can my mailService can be null? I don't understand

Comment: You are right! I used it in another class. But how can I call that function in another class?

Comment: I resolved. I wrote that function into MailService class then I can use it correctly. Thanks!